# Не присваивается значение переменной

Tags: php, операторы, тернарный-оператор

Доброго дня.

Дело такое, в тернарном операторе отказывается принимать значение переменная.

Пробую так:

```
    $msg = (!$setSettings->rowCount()) ? $error[4] :  'Настройки сохранены!';
```

`var_dump($msg)` отдаёт NULL

И так тоже NULL

```
(!$setSettings->rowCount()) ? $msg = $error[4] : $msg =  'Настройки сохранены!';
```

Выходит, что косяк, собственно, в моих кривых руках, но хотелось бы так же знать причину такого поворота событий.

Кто подскажет? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужно проверить, что возвращает `$setSettings->rowCount()`. Прямо вывести с помощью `print_r`, либо сделать так: `(boolean)$setSettings->rowCount()`

Comment: А в `$error[4]` не может ли случайно NULL лежать? Сделайте `var_dump($error[4])`.

Comment: @MAXOPKA, `$setSettings->rowCount() возвращает 1.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в `$error[4]` лежит сообщение об ошибке.

Через var_dump() переменные отдаются.

Comment: Что именно там лежит? Проверьте и напишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. скорее всего какая-то опечатка. Включить `error_reporting(E_ALL)` и **НИКОГДА** не выключать.
2. Сама практика подобных проверок, хоть и очень распространена, но не несет ни малейшего смысла. Никаких "$error[4]" в принципе не должно быть. Если запись в БД не добавляется, то это может произойти только из-за серьезной ошибки БД. Если с БД происходит серьезная ошибка, то д**о проверки rowCount() дело вообще не должно дойти**. А должно быть выброшено исключение, которое породит показ стандартной 503 ошибки пользователю, безо всяких "$error[4]"

Не надо замусоривать код бессмысленными проверками.

Comment: Cпасибо за объяснения и наставления. 

Сейчас исправлю.